# why java List interface implements 10 methods of(..) instead of just one varargs version?

Tags: java

I find it strange that in the List interface are defined 10 methods of(...)

```
 static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10)
```

instead of just

```
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    static <E> List<E> of(E... elements){...}
```

Actually, if I look at the implementation of the varargs version it's even more strange...(a switch on 0,1,2, n elements...)

Any reason for that?

Comment: Is the source you're looking at online somewhere you could link to? At a guess, I would say **performance**, but the actual implementation would probably give something more specific to say.

Comment: My guess is that the interface was written before Java allowed varargs.

Comment: @user949300 your guess is wrong, this method was added long after varargs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With absolutely no prior knowledge of the specific case, I would guess: **performance**.

Given a function with a fixed set of parameters, a compiler can optimise how those parameters are laid out in memory, and even optimise the entire function to a fixed set of processor instructions.

A generalised implementation instead needs machinery for detecting the number of parameters actually passed, collecting them into some intermediate representation, and iterating over them.

Consider an example of `sum`, in an imaginary language, implemented variadically:

```
function sum(int[] ...args) {
    local accumulator = 0;
    foreach ( args as next_arg ) {
        accumulator += next_arg;
    }
    return accumulator;
}
```

Even without knowing the low-level mechanics of passing and allocating variables, we can see that there's a lot going on here. Now compare to implementations with fixed argument lists:

```
function sum(int a) { return a; }
function sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
function sum(int a, int b, int c) { return a + b + c; }
function sum(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return a + b + c + d; }
```

Here, no intermediate storage needs to be allocated for `args` and `accumulator`, and the implementations are easy to map to low-level instructions.

While it's possible for a sufficiently powerful compiler to generate the optimised cases from the generalised one, it's far from easy. So where performance matters more than human convenience, it can be worth hand-crafting at least some of the cases.

Comment: it makes a lot of sense indeed...

Comment: @IMDoP My bad, I mixed up languages when reading the question.  Your answer makes sense, it will be a reasonable performance boost.